# Store time values where their numerical base 1 is in minutes rather than days?

Tags: excel, datetime, time, format

I am trying to alter a spreadsheet that reports the duration of events and displays them as hh:mm. This spreadsheet is sent out automatically and used by hundreds of people, most of whom don't have high excel proficiency. When the data is used people want to use that data in the form of hours or minutes rather than days. I can easily convert a day to a minute or hour by multiplying, but the other people using this spreadsheet would probably get flipped upside down if 00:30 got shown as 0.02 when it is used as a number.

Basically, for an hour and a half long event, I want to be able to display 01:30 but have it stored as either 90 or 1.5. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what is the data type of the cell (Text or Date/Time)?  How is the data being generated?

Comment: I agree with Glenn G that more info is needed as to the data type. Assuming it were the other way around, and the data type is date/time... it would be simple to change 1:30 into 90 would be to just change the number format to [mm] but since you want to go the other direction it would be a bit more complicated

Comment: It is being grabbed from a system that records how many minutes a machine is offline. The data comes in as minutes as a numerical string. The current system then converts it to hh:mm format and into a text string. I am wanting to change it so it stays numerical, so people can manipulate the data.